# Google Maps GMap2 not defined?

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting an error while using the Google Maps Javascript API:

> GMap2 in not defined

The offending line is:

```
 map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
```

Comment: Probably your google maps api library is not getting loaded properly or you are trying to use library before it is loaded....

Comment: What version of the api are you using? `GMap2` would not be defined in v3.

Comment: Now i use V2 issue fixed. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used V3 so that i faced error. Now i'm using v2, the issue is resolved. thanks for all.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA" 
            type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of solving the error you shifted to using an API that will be deprecated in May 2013 ?
Now you would have to solve this problem again anyways :)
[Link here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/basics)

> Note: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010. The V2 API will continue to work until May 19, 2013. We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API.